# How to write a C program that determines if input is prime and numeric

Tags: c, validation, primes, numeric

I'm trying to write a programme with C that asks for a number to be input and then determines whether or not it is a prime number. If the input is a non-numeric character or string, it outputs the message INVALID INPUT. I have managed to create code that can determine if a number is prime and also if it is non-numeric but when I try and combine them, it doesn't work. E.g if I input a non-numeric value it will output the correct message but when I input a numeric value, nothing happens and I'm not sure why. Can anybody help?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define FALSE 0
#define TRUE 1

int numeric( char *string )
{
    int i, valid;
    valid = TRUE;

    if (string[i] < '0' || string[i] >'9')
        valid = FALSE;
    return valid;
}

void main()
{
    char number[5];
    printf("Please enter a decimal number>");
    gets( number );

    if (numeric(number) == TRUE)
    {
        int n, i, a = 0;
        scanf_s("%d", &n);

        for (i = 2; i <= n / 2; ++i)
        {
            if (n%i == 0)
            {
                a = 1;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (n == 1)
        {
            printf("1 isn't a prime number.");
        }
        else
        {
            if (a == 0)
                printf("number entered is a prime number");
            else
                printf("number entered is not a prime number");
        }
    }
    else 
        printf("INVALID INPUT \n"); 
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Be sure to take the
[tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and visit the [help
center](https://stackoverflow.com/help). Your code has a problem which may or may not be related to the behaviour you describe, but it needs to be solved, otherwise you are invoking dreaded undefined behaviour. You're using uninitialized `i` as an index into your string in `numeric`. It's up to the compiler to determine what `i` will be, which is a horrible idea in general. If you're lucky, it's gonna be 0. If not, who knows?

Comment: See [Why the `gets()` function is so dangerous it should never be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the bug mentioned in @Michail's comment (failing to initialise `i` to zero in `numeric`:

Your problem is that in the truthy branch of `if (numeric(number))`, you call `scanf_s`, which will try to read new input from `STDIN`. You've already read the number from `STDIN` in your call to `gets`. The behaviour you observe ("nothing happens") is to be expected: your program is waiting for you to enter more input.

You leave yourself open to buffer overflow but that's a separate issue.